# git merge or rebase, feature branch to another running feature branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have following branches

- master
- release
- dev

  - feature-1
  - feature-2
- long-time-feature

All feature branch belong to dev branch and merge into dev branch after completed. 
I do it by following way

```
git checkout feature-1
git rebase dev
(remove all conflict, if exist and then commit)
git checkout dev
git rebase feature-1
git push origin dev
```

Above process is good, properly history managed and everything is looking Ok. But I have another branch **long-time-feature**. It will release some month later and I need to update it by dev branch (After every new feature completion). So same above thing applying with **long-time-feature** branch without rebasing to dev.

```
git checkout **long-time-feature**
git rebase dev
(remove all conflict, if exist and then commit and push it)
```

But now next time I will rebase it dev then all conflict repeat again and lots of commit increase when push it. Its too hard to every time remove conflict again and again. :( So any good way to up to date my **long-time-feature** branch with dev.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There are no miracles and long living branches are destined to cause merge conflicts. You might though try to minimize their damage by one of the following options:

#### merge instead of rebase

This way you resolve conflicts once per merge and keep the original history of the long living branch

Cons: the history is not that linear anymore; more difficult to revert a dev feature if decided to revoke such

#### squash long living branch history

Chances are you have to resolve the same conflict for subsequent commits of the long living branch upon rebase. You may improve this by squashing the history into larger, preferably one, commit.

The downside is less history.